# Exclusive test result viewing privileges in Moodle

Tags: moodle

There is a Moodle system with the following:
There are 20 courses a year, every course has 2 teachers. In the end of each course there is a final exam.
Right now - every teacher can see the results of all the exams.
Wanted state - every teacher can access only the results of the courses he teaches.
Is that posible?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the teachers are getting their permissions from systemwide roles rather than course roles. Try going to Site Administration > Users > Permissions > Assign System Roles and see if there's a system role that they all have. If so, click on it and remove them from that role.

Then, add teacher permissions just for the course they teach. Enter the course and enroll the teacher, then follow [the instructions in the documentation](http://docs.moodle.org/23/en/Assign_roles#Course_context) for assigning course roles. This may cause them to have both a student and a teacher role, but that's not a problem; the system will treat them as a teacher.